# chmod +x doesn`t work

Tags: cinnamon, chmod, mint

I am trying to install this [widget](http://www.noobslab.com/2012/10/install-colors-conky-in-ubuntulinux.html). When I use `chmod +x .start-conky` nothing heapens, file .start-conky still is a text file.

Comment: We only support Ubuntu and official derivatis. Mint is not one of those. Please use http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The fact is that you use linux mint should be irrelevant, just ask about chmod.

Comment: Voted to close, but quick answer: altough you didn't saw any change in whatever file manager you're using, the file should have been still marked as executable. Check this with `ls -l`

Comment: @Serg I doubt that. This is going to be Mint related since it is -not- normal behaviour.  Besides that: you missed to change the tags.

Comment: @Rinzwind I think the OP is misunderstanding what chmod is supposed to be doing or how it normally behaves, and it's less about abnormal behavior. The fact that OP says "still text file" means they expect it to turn into something else, which it shouldn't

Comment: Indeed, kos. But i still dont get it why it opens with the text editor, and not just executes, like it was in my Live USB. Also when i type 'conky' in my terminal i get:  sh: 1: /home/oleg/.conky/conkyIp: Permission denied
If i just quit terminal - Conky continue to work.

Comment: Then the problem is that `/home/oleg/.conky/conkyIp`, which is run by `.start-conky`, is not executable

Comment: Also this is one of the reason why Mint is not supported, just a difference in the file manager settings (`nautilus` on Ubuntu doesn't run executable scripts upon double click) makes everything harder to debug

Comment: @Serg see kos's comment; he is correct. This is a filemanager problem = Mint specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file `.start-conky` still is a text file. Technically, `chmod` adds executable permissions. It doesn't change a text file to executable file, but rather gives a file permission to be executed.

What you could try doing is to remove leading dot (even though this should not have any effect, a `.file` is simply a hidden file) and remove that dot in all subsequent steps

`cd && wget -O start-conky http://drive.noobslab.com/data/conky/start-conky`

`-O` option specifies output file's name, that's all

Comment: Thanks. Should i delete this theme? Although i have another issue. When i type 'conky' in my terminal i get: sh: 1: /home/oleg/.conky/conkyIp: Permission denied If i just quit terminal - Conky continue to work.

Comment: @Serg: Could you drop by the [Ask Ubuntu general room chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) and ping me for the edits to the original question?

Comment: @Fabby I am struggling to get into the chat there. Says I'm supposed to be logged in , even though I am

Comment: @oOBunny What is the output of `ls -l  /home/oleg/.conky/conkyIp` ? you might want to do `chmod +x /home/oleg/.conky/conkyIp` . Also, I looked into `.start-conky` file, there is a line saying `sleep 20` , which is kinda long, you might want to change it to like `10` or `5` seconds

Comment: @Serg Thanks, it helped to get rid of that message "Permission denied"